# Losing selected tabs after asp post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me crazy since two days. I have a aspx page with dropdowns. Each dropdown changes dynamically based on other dropdown selection. The code is

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="panel panel-gray">
 <div class="panel-heading">Filter Configuration</div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="DdlProject" runat="server"   OnTextChanged="DdlProject_TextChanged"
   AddJQueryReference="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlProject_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Style SelectBoxWidth="165" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="165" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="240" DropDownBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle box-height" SelectBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle text-bold"/>
    <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Project" />
  </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-gray" style="margin-top: 30px">
 <div class="panel-heading">Additional Parameters</div>
 <div class="panel-body">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li role="presentation" id="users-btn" onclick="showUsersDiv()" class="active"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="powertrain-btn" onclick="showPowerTrainDiv()"><a href="#">Powertrain</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div id="users" class="additional-param"> 
   <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="DdlOperator" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlOperator_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Style SelectBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="200" DropDownBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle" SelectBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle text-bold"/>
    <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Operator" />
   </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
  </div>
   <div id="powertrain" class="additional-param" style="display: none;">
   <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="DdlEngine" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlEngine_SelectedIndexChanged" >
     <Style SelectBoxWidth="150" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="150" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="200" DropDownBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle" SelectBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle text-bold"/>
        <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Engine"/>
   </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Javascript for navigation tabs

```
 function showUsersDiv() {
    $("#users").show();
    $("#powertrain").hide();
    $("#dyno").hide();
    $("#hex").hide();
    resetActiveParamButtons();
    $("#users-btn").addClass("active");
}

function showPowerTrainDiv() {
    $("#users").hide();
    $("#powertrain").show();
    $("#dyno").hide();
    $("#hex").hide();
    resetActiveParamButtons();
    $("#powertrain-btn").addClass("active");
}
```

In an updatePanel I placed two bootstrap panels One panel has few dropdowns. The other panel has navigation tabs. And each navigation tabs has dropdowns. All these dropdowns from both panels depend on each other's selection. So I cannot place those two panels in different UpdatePanels. No matter which tab I select, after postback it is resetting to Users tab. How can I do this. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: its not so easy, after what user is select with javascript, if you need it after the post back you need to send it back to the server, and then re-init the panel base on this selection. The easy way is to do what you have to do with javascript, and after the post back just get the results...

Comment: @Anthony View state is already enabled.

Comment: @Aristos I am sorry I did not get that. Could you please be more specific about the solution. Thanks

Comment: What you do with javascript - will be lost after the post back. To keep it, you need to save it to some input control, post it back, and then re-use it. Its a complex process, so its better to keep it simple... use the javascript to complete all your action so after the post back just get the user output and save it.

Comment: @Aristos The use of the update panel already indicates that the user will be doing some form of server posting back (on a partial basis), so saying everything is client is not entirely correct.  Secondly, You can do server posting (web service, etc.) with JavaScript, as is very typically done on mobile single page apps, where you are not navigating anywhere.  You are right that you would need to "tell" the server that something has changed if you plan to post.  Alternatively, disable auto-postback and manage it yourself.